# How to play sound on an Android device automatically

Tags: android

I am building an App and have created a splash screen and want sound to be accompanied with it. So far all I have managed to do is create a media player to play the sound file when a button is clicked. I want the sound to play as soon as the splash screen loads.
If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

So far I haven't been able to find any information on this.

Comment: There's nothing different between the actions inside the onClick and the code in onCreate... Just move the media player

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! I'm annoyed it was something so simple which I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Call the MediaPlayer class, give her a soundtrack and play the music, after splash screen go off stop the player

Answer (score 0):

use this code in thread which you use to wait splash screen for some seconds

```
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
 player.setDataSource("/sdcard/audiotrack.mp3");
 player.prepare();
 player.start();
```

To stop playing on other screen

```
 protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
    if(mp.isPlaying()){ //Must check if it's playing, otherwise it may be a NPE
     mp.pause(); //Pauses the sound
     ur.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
     }
  }
```